# `std::alignment_of` versus `alignof`

Tags: c++, memory-alignment, c++17, alignof

I've just stumbled upon the [`std::alignment_of`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/alignment_of) type trait, and its soon-to-be friend `std::alignment_of_v`. They seem to have been specifically designed to be equivalent to a plain call to [`alignof`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/alignof), and the future addition of the `_v` helper indicates that it's not just a legacy bit.

What is the use of `std::alignment_of` (`_v`), when we have `alignof` ?

Comment: To have true error when use with expression instead of use *gnu-alignof-expression* :-).

Answer (score 22, accepted):

They are almost completely redundant.  As @Revolver noted, they were introduced in different papers, and `alignment_of` comes from `boost` nearly verbatim.

But that does not mean the trait is useless.

A `template<class...>class` can be passed to other `template`s and used with metaprogramming.  Operators like `alignof` cannot: you would have to write the `template<class>class alignment_of` before you could pass it to metaprogramming facilities.

Now the same could be said of `sizeof` needing a `std::size_of<class>` template.

...

The addition of `_v` was because they swept *every* `::value` `integral_constant`-type template in `std` and added a `_v` variable template.  Considering which ones where worthy and which not would be bikeshed painting and nearly pointless: it is easier to do every one than spend effort picking the worthy ones to do.  It being done is not evidence the feature is not obsolete.

Comment: The usefulness of the metafunction itself hadn't crossed my mind. That is a very good point, thank you !

Answer (score 5):

The `std::alignment_of` is introduced as port of Boost type traits library. It predates C++11 and `alignof` keyword. That trait was superseded by `alignof` operator, but it was kept mainly for compatibility purposes (so you could just replace `boost::` with `std::`) and `_v` variable alias is introduced for consistency with other parts of the library.

Comment: From your answer it seems as if they were introduced separately, when they were not (both since C++11).

Comment: @black technically they were introduced separately (in different papers). The point of my answer was that it was a part of pre-C++11 library before inclusion in standard.

Comment: `alignment_of` was in TR1.

Answer (score 1):

One nice thing I found in practice is that `alignof` is simply syntactically invalid for old code, whereas `alignment_of` is just a standard template. So you can stay compatible with older compilers by providing an implementation of `alignment_of` using whatever alternative syntax your compiler accepts, then use that everywhere.

Comment: Can you give an example where alignof would've been syntactically incorrect but alignment_of would've worked?

Comment: @AyxanHaqverdili: Anywhere in **old** (pre-C++11) code.

Comment: Oh, if you're bringing in your own implementation that just masks compiler-specific code in pre-C++11 code, you could also implement `alignof` as a macro.

Comment: @AyxanHaqverdili: Sure, you can implement lots of things as a macro.